# Why is a JavaScript question put on hold at Stack Overflow if it is in a WordPress page?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, moderation, scope

My question has been put on hold for being irrelevant to Stack Overflow, but it is primarily a JavasScript question. One of the users who put it on hold, said it should be posted on the WordPress Stack Exchange. When I posted it there, they said it was a JavaScript question.

My post that is on hold for not being about JavaScript:

[How to make preloader execute on image load in javascript for wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250868/how-to-make-preloader-execute-on-image-load-in-javascript-for-wordpress-site)

And the post at WordPress Stack Exchange where they point out it is a JavaScript question:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110232/script-help-for-a-preloader-hide-page-until-all-elements-load

I'm not sure what the rep repercussions are in this situation but they should be disregarded for the proper handling of posts.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's off-topic. I do have a hard time figuring out what your actual question is though.

Comment: To hide the overlay div with javascript (jquery will work for overlay div hide). Need to find a method to hide the div right before the slider starts (when the slider images render). Having trouble finding the object or event to trigger or attach to javascript. I think some of the confusion is from me trying to clarify that this was being implemented in wordpress and so jquery wasn't going to work for the first function (create overlay div). Otherwise this question would be a duplicate from 2004.